# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app AngularJS + webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use webpack and yarn with an existing AngularJS application but I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module datepicker due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'datepicker' is not available! You either 
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I looked in several issue in stackoverfolow similar to mine but wasn't able to fix it.
I'm able to see all imported module into the generated output file or generated vendor.js file but it seems that I'm missing something.
below is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "myapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"build": "webpack",
"watch": "yarn run build --watch"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"alasql": "^0.4.2",
"angular": "1.5.3",
"angular-animate": "1.5.3",
"angular-aria": "1.5.3",
"angular-cookies": "1.5.3",
"angular-dynamic-locale": "^0.1.32",
"angular-gridster": "^0.13.14",
"angular-growl-v2": "^0.7.5",
"angular-jk-rating-stars": "^1.0.8",
"angular-material": "^1.1.5",
"angular-messages": "1.5.3",
"angular-nvd3": "^1.0.9",
"angular-sanitize": "1.5.3",
"angular-touch": "1.5.3",
"angular-translate": "^2.15.2",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "^2.15.2",
"angular-translate-storage-cookie": "^2.15.2",
"angular-translate-storage-local": "^2.15.2",
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "1.2.4",
"angular-ui-grid": "^4.0.7",
"angular-ui-router": "0.2.13",
"angularjs-slider": "^6.4.0",
"bootstrap-duallistbox": "^3.0.6",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"ng-idle": "^1.3.2",
"ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
"ui-select": "0.19.8",
"underscore": "^1.8.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
"webpack-css-loaders": "^1.0.0",
"webpack-uglify-js-plugin": "^1.1.9"
}
}
```

and here is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const webpackUglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack-uglify-js-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
entry: {
    app: [
        './src/main/webapp/app/app.js',
        './src/main/webapp/app/assets/css/appCSS.css',
    ],
    vendor: [
      'angular'
    , 'angular-animate'
    , 'angular-sanitize'
    , 'angular-cookies'
    , 'angular-touch'
    , 'angular-messages'
    , 'angular-aria'
    , 'angular-ui-router'
    , 'angular-dynamic-locale'
    , 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker'
    , 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/modal'
    , 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/tabs'
    , 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/dropdown'
    , 'angular-ui-grid'
    , 'angular-nvd3'
    , 'angular-gridster'
    , 'angular-material'
    , 'angularjs-slider'
    , 'angular-growl-v2'
    , 'angular-translate'
    , 'angular-translate-loader-static-files'
    , 'angular-translate-storage-cookie'
    , 'angular-translate-storage-local'
    , 'angular-jk-rating-stars'
    , 'ngstorage'
    , 'ui-select'
    , 'ng-idle'
    , 'jquery'
    , 'jquery-ui'
    , 'moment'
    , 'underscore'
    , 'alasql'
    ]
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/output'),
    filename: 'app.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            /*options: {
                presets: ['env']
            }*/
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, //to support eg. background-image property 
        loader: "file-loader",
        query: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'images/'
                //the images will be emmited to public/assets/images/ folder 
                //the images will be put in the DOM <style> tag as eg. background: url(assets/images/image.png); 
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, //to support @font-face rule 
        loader: "url-loader",
        query: {
            limit: '10000',
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                //the fonts will be emmited to public/assets/fonts/ folder 
                //the fonts will be put in the DOM <style> tag as eg. @font-face{ src:url(assets/fonts/font.ttf); }  
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: "css-loader"
        })
    }]
},
node: {
    fs: "empty"
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    new webpackUglifyJsPlugin({
        cacheFolder: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/cached_uglify/'),
        debug: true,
        minimize: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        output: {
            comments: false
        },
        compressor: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.js',
        minChunks: Infinity
    })

]
};
```

and here is my app module

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router';
//this will only import needed model from bootstrap
import datepicker from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker/datepicker.js';
import modal from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/modal';
import tabs from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/tabs';
import dropdown from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/dropdown';
import ngIdle from 'ng-idle';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';
import ngSanitize from 'angular-sanitize';
import ngCookies from 'angular-cookies';
import 'angular-translate';
import 'angular-dynamic-locale';
import 'angular-growl-v2';
import appDirective from './directives/appDirective.js';
import appConfig from './config/appConfig.js';
import appRun from './run/appRun.js';
import appController from './controllers/appController.js';

angular.module("app",
    [   'ui.router'
      , 'datepicker'
      , 'modal'
      , 'tabs'
      , 'dropdown'
      , 'ngIdle'
      , 'ngAnimate'
      , 'ngSanitize'
      , 'ngCookies'
      , 'pascalprecht.translate'
      , 'tmh.dynamicLocale'
      , 'angular-growl'
    ])
    .directive(appDirective)
    .config(appConfig)
    .run(appRun)
    .controller(appController);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 4th row of your app module be `import datepicker from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker';`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this lane should be wrote this way either

```
import datepicker from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker/datepicker.js';


import datepicker from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker';
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove the '' that surround the module name as mentioned in the ui-bootstrap [example](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)

```
import accordion from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/accordion';
import datepicker from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/datepicker';

angular.module('myModule', [accordion, datepicker]);
```

or in you module import it like this `'ui.bootstrap.datepicker'`